# Exporting a FreeCAD model to Blender

Tags: video

I am an Engineering student and I am designing some electrical device on FreeCAD. I am a complete beginner but I am interested in Blender because what I am planning to do is to create some fancy advertising (commercial) video of my product. Now, my question is can I reuse the models I created in FreeCAD when doing the commercial video in Blender or are these softwares incompatible?
I know this question may sound trivial but since I am a beginner and as confused as I am, I want to make sure that I am the right place, opting for Blender in order to get my commercial video done.

Comment: It depends on wether FreeCAD is able to export a format that blender can import like .obj, .fbx, .dae,...

Comment: The format of the files bear the extension `.FCStd`. And I use latest version which is FreeCAD 0.18. Do you think these files will be supported?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

.FCStd is a native, software specific format. You can't import or export it within Blender. You can however use an exchange format. According to wikipedia FreeCAD can import and export .stl, .obj, and .dae (among others). Those three are ones that blender can also import and export.

Answer (score 0):

Yorik van Havre wrote a great Blender addon which allows you to import FreeCAD files directly into Blender.
It depends a bit on the Python versions of both your FreeCAD and Blender software, but it is possible e.g. via conda to create the correct versions yourself.
You can find the details and the addon on Yorik's [github](https://gist.github.com/yorikvanhavre/680156f59e2b42df8f5f5391cae2660b)
Make sure to read the comments to get an idea of the necessary Python versions.